# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...CsrfTokenManager::isTokenValid() must be an instance of ...\CsrfToken, string given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

Currently, I am updating the system running on the existing Symfony 2.3 (currently 3.0.9), and I am verifying the operation.
When I tried the ability to change the status of an article to the selected status, I got an error. Do you have any advice on how to determine the cause?

**Code**
BaseArticleController.php

```
    /**
     * Article status change
     */
    protected function updateArticleStatusAction(Request $request, $ids)
    {
        // CSRF token check
        $token = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

        if (!$this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->isTokenValid('authenticate', $token))
 {
            throw new HttpException("400", "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit
 the form.");
        }

        // Check status
        $articleStatus = $request->request->get("articleStatus");
        if (!in_array($articleStatus, Parameters::getArticleStatusKeys())) {
            throw new HttpException("400", "articleStatus is invalid.");
        }

        // Status change
        try {
            $ids = explode(',', $ids);
            $count = $this->getArticleService()->updateArticleStatus($ids, $articleStatus, $t
his->getShop());
            if ($count) {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "{$count}The status of the article has changed.");
            }
        } catch (ArticleValidationException $e) {
            $article = $e->getArticle();
            $statusArray = Parameters::getArticleStatus();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'error',
                sprintf(
                    "Article ID:% d could not be "% s". Please check your input.",
                    $article->getId(),
                    $statusArray[$article->getArticleStatus()]
                )
            );
        }

        // redirect
        $backurl = $request->query->get("backurl");
        if (!$backurl) {
            $backurl = $this->generateUrl($this->indexRoute);
        }
        return $this->redirect($backurl);
    }
```

ArticleController.php

```
    /**
     * Article status change
     *
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Route("/article/{ids}/articleStatus")
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_HQ_MANAGE")
     */
    public function updateArticleStatusAction(Request $request, $ids)
    {
        return parent::updateArticleStatusAction($request, $ids);
    }
```

index.html.twig

```
    {# Status change form #}
    <form method="post" class="updateArticleStatus" data-url="{{ path("ahi_sp_admin_hq_article_updatearticlestatus", {"ids": "__ids__"}) }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="methods" value="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token("authenticate") }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="articleStatus" value="">
    </form>
```

security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area2:
            pattern:    ^/admin/sp/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /admin/sp/login
                check_path:  /admin/sp/login_check
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:            /admin/sp/
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

            logout:
                path:   /admin/sp/logout
                target: /admin/sp/login

            remember_me:
                secret:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 2592000 # 30 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
                always_remember_me: true

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /admin/login
                check_path:  /admin/login_check

                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:            /admin/
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/login
```

Comment: The answer below should get you past your particular error but you really have your work cut out for you as 2.3 is quite ancient.  It might be better to start with a current version (either 4.4 or 5.2 depending on your goals) and then do a copy/paste update.  If you really want to continue down your current path then first update to 2.8.  With 2.8 much of your 2.3 code should continue to work but you will get warnings about things like your csrf tokens.  Resolve the warnings then move to 3.4.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you for your comment.
It seems better to check the caution statement carefully in 2.8.
When is it better to copy / paste the code directly into Symfony 4.4?

Comment: There have been quite a few changes made in the overall structure of Symfony over the years.  If the app needs to be maintained indefinitely then I lean in favor of taking the time to copy/paste/modify.  If nothing else, you will learn quite a bit about 4.4.  If you just desperately need to get something running under an updated PHP version and don't plan on doing much with the app then the usual upgrade process might be best.  And don't overlook the possibility of moving directly to 5.x.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you. It's better to decide according to the size of the app. It's not that complicated, so I'd like to continue updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message also give enough detail for you to debug, argument 1 (in your case is "authenticate") must be an crsf Token. Try this:

```
$csrf_token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $token);

$this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->isTokenValid($csrf_token)
```